# How to write arrays of integers to binary files?

Tags: c, arrays, file, dynamic

Hello I am trying to write a program that stores two separate integer arrays and one float array, my code below does this but without the array part, in other words I can write a single digit to a file and print it back out, but I cannot find out how to do the exact same thing but with an array (Dynamically Allocated). Here is the code below: it takes three values (part number, quantity and price) and repeats taking the values in until the user enters 0 for part number (pn).
Then writes that data into a file called "inventory.txt", then in the same program, open the file for reading and display those values back on the terminal.

So far, the program can only handle one number in the variables at a time(duh), I just can't figure out how to do the same thing but with an array that gets bigger with each added element.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){


printf("This program stores an invetory: ");



int i=0, holdr, k;  //declarations of needed variables
int pn, q;
float p;

FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("inventory.txt","w+b");   //open file

while(holdr!=0){     //aka while pn!=0, for some reason needed a separate variable to run loop coorectly

printf("Please enter item data (part number, quantity, price): ");
scanf("%d,%d,%f",*pn,*q,*p);//scan numbers into respective variables, need to turn these into ARRAYS


            //pn = malloc((i+1) * sizeof(int));  (setting aside this part of code as I can't get it to work properly at all (for the dynamic aspect of the program(array increases in size as user enters more digits)))
            //q = malloc((i+1) * sizeof(int));
            //p = malloc((i+1) * sizeof(int));


fwrite(&pn,sizeof(int),1,fp);   //write to file
fwrite(&q,sizeof(int),1,fp);
fwrite(&p,sizeof(int),1,fp);

holdr=pn;  //set pn=holdr for the running loop 
}


rewind(fp);//back to beginning of file


fp=fopen("inventory.txt","r+b");  //open for reading


if (fp == NULL){  //check for file
printf("nah");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


fread(&pn,sizeof(int),k,fp);  //read and then print the values in the file stored in the specified variables, nned to turn these variables into ARRAYS
printf("%d\t" , **pn);
fread(&q,sizeof(int),k,fp);
printf("%d\t", **q);
fread(&p,sizeof(int),k,fp);
printf("%f\n", **p);








fclose(fp);//close file


return 0;}
```

Here is the second try I made, a lot closer, but it won't compile as the cast of malloc inside the while loop is incorrect and I have no idea what is the correct way to allocate the space through every iteration.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){


printf("This program stores an invetory: ");



int i=0, holdr, k;
int pn[1], q[1];
float p[1];

FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("inventory.txt","w+b");

while(holdr!=0){

printf("Please enter item data (part number, quantity, price): ");
scanf("%d,%d,%f",&pn[i],&q[i],&p[i]);


pn=malloc((i+1) * sizeof(int));
q=malloc((i+1) * sizeof(int));
p=malloc((i+1) * sizeof(float));


fwrite(&pn[i],sizeof(int),k+1,fp);


fwrite(&q[i],sizeof(int),k+1,fp);


fwrite(&p[i],sizeof(float),k+1,fp);


holdr=pn[i];
i++;
}


rewind(fp);


fp=fopen("inventory.txt","r+b");


if (fp == NULL){
printf("nah");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


fread(&pn,sizeof(int),k,fp);
printf("%d\t" , pn[2]);
fread(&q,sizeof(int),k,fp);
printf("%d\t", q[2]);
fread(&p,sizeof(int),k,fp);
printf("%f\n", p[2]);








fclose(fp);


return 0;}
```

Comment: how about looping over the members of the array and calling fwrite for each one

Comment: @pm100 ok but how do I size them in the beginning so I can make them bigger to compensate for however many integers/floaters the user enters?

Comment: u mean when reading back. Store a size as the firs integer, then store the values

Comment: ? The size increases by one piece of data every iteration of the loop, so I can't really do that as the size is not pre-determined I thought?

Comment: Are you asking how to make the file store the size, or how to know how many pieces of data the user will enter?

Comment: but when you come to write the array you must know the size. You will have to keep track of it somehow

Comment: the file store the size, but the size will increment by one through every iteration of the loop, it's some sort of allocation function

Comment: I am having trouble allocating the proper space for the array, I am keeping track of the size with an index variable @immibis

Comment: if you have semi working code then please post it so we can see it

Comment: where on comments or post? @pm100

Comment: in the question  - edit it.

Comment: you say the file is called inventory.txt - that sounds like a text ile, not binary

Comment: read all teh data into memory in the while. loop, then when the user signals the end, write teh count the loop over the array and write teh values

Comment: what is the format for binary

Comment: @pm100 like I am doin that for sure, but still the problem lies in the allocation of memory. (malloc functions)

Comment: You declared your variables as 1-element arrays, not pointers.  If you want to use dynamic memory, declare then as pointers e.g `int *pn;`, `float *p;` -- i also notice you are reading into these arrays _before_ allocating.  And you are re-allocating with `malloc` in the loop instead of using `realloc`.  All this is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: use realloc not malloc, and no you are writing them out as you read them. write them out at the end of the loop. End of thread here

Comment: @steakfry I see that you're asking 3 different questions for the same program / problem. Please consolidate them into one question.